# Creating a Searchable PDF Archive of Publications

Tags: search

We are a not for profit association that produces a quarterly publication of about 45 pages. Want to create a members only archive of back issues in pdf format. This would be used for research (not a replacement for hardcopy) so we would like to be able to search all or as many issues as possible at one time by word. We have an index of articles by category and author so we can link directly to an issue from there. Estimate that each issue at low resolution will result in a 20 meg file. Currently have about 200 issues. Consider it like a library. Any ideas, thoughts, suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not the place for plugin recommendations (too much personal bias, I guess), I have used the WP Google Search plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-google-search/ which integrates with Google Custom Search Engine.

All you need is a free Google CSE key; enter that in the plugin's settings, and that's it. Seems to work well with the PDF's on the site that I put it on.